# Can't replace \r character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, notepad++, newline

I experiment a lot and creating HTML templates (blank, canvas, app, etc.) everytime I code is a little frustrating. I can create macros in Notepad++ for various templates, but doing this manually is not that productive. Since I've figured out how the macros are saved, in `shortcuts.xml` file, in the following format:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands>
        <Shortcut id="42023" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="81" />
    </InternalCommands>
    <Macros>
        <Macro name="Blank HTML5" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&lt;" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="!" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="D" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="O" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="C" />
```

I thought about creating the templates programmatically and this is what I came up with: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/zpx5gc7L/)

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById("input");
var outputBox = document.getElementById("output");
var convertButton = document.getElementById("convert");

var dict = [
  [/</, "&lt;"],
  [/>/, "&gt;"],
  [/\r/, "&#x000D;"],
  [/\n/, "&#x000A;"],
];

convertButton.onclick = function convertTextToMacro() {
  var chars = inputBox.value.split("");
  var macro = '<Macro name="" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">\r\n';
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    var c = chars[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < dict.length; j++) {
      c = c.replace(dict[j][0], dict[j][1]);
    }
    macro += '    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="' + c + '">\r\n';
  }
  macro += '</Macro>';
  outputBox.value = macro;
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  background: gainsboro;
}

#main {
  display: table;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

textarea {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#input {
  height: 150px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <textarea id="input" placeholder="Input">
<html>
    <body></body>
</html>
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" id="convert" value="Create macro" />
  <textarea id="output" placeholder="Output"></textarea>
</div>
```

There are 4 characters that need to be escaped:

```
var dict = [
    [/</,   "&lt;"],
    [/>/,   "&gt;"],
    [/\r/,  "&#x000D;"],
    [/\n/,  "&#x000A;"],
];
```

I can replace `<`, `>`, and `\n`, but can't seem to replace `\r`. Weird thing is this seems to happen only in this particular case. And if I omit `\n`

```
var dict = [
    [/</,   "&lt;"],
    [/>/,   "&gt;"],
    [/\r/,  "&#x000D;"],
    // [/\n/,  "&#x000A;"],
];
```

I get a different output: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/zpx5gc7L/3/)

In the following example:

```
var greet = "Hello\rWorld".replace(/\r/, "&#x000D;");
console.log(greet);  // "Hello&#x000D;World"

var chr = "\r".split("")[0].replace(/\r/, "&#x000D;");
console.log(chr);   // "&#x000D;"
```

`\r` is replaced. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing the trailing comma in your `var dict` is just due to quick copy/paste?

Comment: @JClaspill Yes. I might need to escape other chars as well, Just couldn't get that far to figure out if there are more. `\r` got in the way.

Comment: In my browser at least, there are no carriage returns `\r` in the input to your jsfiddles.

Comment: @WillBarnwell That was silly of me. I just assumed `\r\n` would also be present since I copied/pasted the code from Notepad++. Theo's answer solved the problem.

Comment: Yep, Theo answered as I wrote that comment, thats a tricky thing about javascript, no matter what youre doing, the browser has access to your text first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not actually have any \r characters in your textarea.

`\r` is a carriage return character, `\n` is a new line character.
On windows every new line is represented by both characters: `\r\n` on linux it's just `\n`.

To save you from having to worry about this the browser is stripping the `\r` and leaving you with just `\n`.

You can see this is the case as you can re-add `\r` characters to go with every `\n` before running your code (this is somewhat pointless but shows the rest of your code is fine)

```
 var inputBox = document.getElementById("input");
 var outputBox = document.getElementById("output");
 var convertButton = document.getElementById("convert");

 var dict = [
   [/</, "&lt;"],
   [/>/, "&gt;"],
   [/\r/, "&#x000D;"],
   [/\n/, "&#x000A;"]
 ];

 convertButton.onclick = function convertTextToMacro() {
   var value = inputBox.value.replace(/\n/g,'\r\n');
   var chars = value.split("");
   var macro = '<Macro name="" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">\r\n';
   for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
     var c = chars[i];
     for (var j = 0; j < dict.length; j++) {
       c = c.replace(dict[j][0], dict[j][1]);
     }
     macro += '    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="' + c + '">\r\n';
   }
   macro += '</Macro>';
   outputBox.value = macro;
 };
```

So the question is do you really need the `\r` characters included? I'm not sure there is a solution with textboxes if you do.

I'm not 100% sure all browsers do this - so it may be worth stripping them before starting just in case `var value = inputBox.value.replace(/\r/g,'');`

Comment: This makes sense. When I examine the `shorcuts.xml` file in which the macros are stored, I can see both the `\r` and `\n`, but I think this is because Notepad++ is using Windows EOL by default. If the browser strips `\r`s, that'd surely mess things up. Fixed it: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/zpx5gc7L/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `\r\n` instead of `\r`

Comment: doesn't work there will never be a character `\r\n` since thats a two character string